# Call a method in my bootstrap ui tooltip

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

For the sake of simplicity, I'm trying to configure my bootstrap tooltip to call an api to pull the correct tooltip text value

```
<i class="fa fa-certificate" 
    tooltip="{{loadTooltipText(paramVal)}}" 
    tooltip-placement="top" 
    tooltip-trigger="mouseenter"></i>
```

But it seems the method is called without the actual mouseenter event, it triggers the method upon loading the scope

```
$scope.loadTooltipText = function (paramVal) {
            data.getTooltipText(paramVal)
                .$promise
                .then(function (resp) {
                    if (resp.Success) {
                        return resp.TooltipText;
                    }
                    else {
                        return "There was a problem loading this";
                    }
                }, function (resp) {
                })
        };
```

Comment: I would suggest putting the method in the {{}}. so `tooltip="{{loadTooltipText(paramVal)}}"`

Comment: Is it possible for paramVal to change at runtime? Ie for there to be multiple tooltip values for a single element depending on things happening on your page? If not, then it makes more sense to only get the value once and store it for reuse. If this is feasible then you could simply create a directive that wraps the one you're currently interacting with. Let me know and I can help you with an implementation of that.